# Exception while executing hadoop job remotely

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to execute a Hadoop job on a remote hadoop cluster. Below is my code.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://server:9000/");
conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "username");

Job job = new Job(conf, "Percentil Ranking");
job.setJarByClass(PercentileDriver.class);
job.setMapperClass(PercentileMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(PercentileReducer.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(TestKey.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(TestData.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(TestKey.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(BaselineData.class);

job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));

FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));

job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

When the job starts executing immediately an exception is thrown before even the map phase.

```
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:226)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:617)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1216)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1197)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:800)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
```

The input file does exist and is a comma separated text file. I am able to execute the job on the hadoop cluster using the `hadoop jar` command with the same input and output. But I can't run it remotely. I am also able to run other jobs remotely.

Can anyone tell me what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "server:9001");` fixed the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You do this:

```
conf.set("fs.default.name", "serverurl");
```

So you are setting the filesystem to the value "serverurl"... which is meaningless.

I'm pretty sure that it works when you simply remove that line from your code.

HTH

Comment: I dont set it to serverurl, I am setting it to the hdfs url. e.g. hdfs://server:9000/. Sorry for the confusion. Updated the question as well.

Comment: Still; try removing that line. You submit the job to a cluster and the cluster should know how to get to the filesystem.

Comment: Yes. But I am executing on a remote cluster. i.e. the job execution code does not run on the cluster. So the job should know the location of the cluster.

Comment: You submit the job to the jobtracker of the cluster; the jobtracker knows where the filesystem is. If it doesn't work that way then is seems you have an ill configured cluster.

Comment: Wait ... did you really say "the job execution code does not run on the cluster" ... that is ... VERY weird! My first reaction: Get a good book: http://basj.es/hadoop

Comment: By 'job execution code' I actually meant the client code that I pasted in the question. It runs on the local machine and not on the cluster. For it to find the remote name node you have to specify the fs.default.name property.